# Toggling class in group of buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, button

I have the following markup for a group of buttons:

```
<div class="btn-group pull-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="today">Today</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="this_week">This Week</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="this_month">This Month</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="custom">Custom</button>
</div>
```

I'm trying to replace class `btn-default` with class `btn-primary` on the button using jQuery so that when clicked, the clicked button will have the following `class="btn btn-primary"`, and any other button in the group with class `btn-primary` will toggle back to `btn-default`.

Is there a more elegant solution to what I have provided below? Do I have to write a function for every button? Also, I risk adding btn `btn-default` to a button which already has that class. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
$("#today").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().find("btn btn-primary").removeClass("btn btn-primary");
    $(this).parent().addClass("btn btn-default");
    $(this).addClass("btn btn-primary");
});
```

Comment: Just to save time: could *everyone* posting an answer take the time to explain their answer, so that people might learn something about what's happening?

Comment: Seconded, answers with no explanation are only half a solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ju1netpa/1/)

```js
$('.btn-group').on('click', '.btn', function() {
  $(this).addClass('btn-primary').siblings().removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default');
});
```

```css
.btn-default {
  color: red;
}
.btn-primary {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group pull-right">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="today">Today</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="this_week">This Week</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="this_month">This Month</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="custom">Custom</button>
</div>
```

1. `$(this)`: is the button that is clicked
2. `addClass('btn-primary')`: Adds specified class to the clicked button
3. `.siblings('.btn')`: will get the siblings(nodes on same level) having `btn` class of `this` element
4. `.removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default')`: Update classes accordingly of `siblings`

Comment: Good solution, please note however that by using siblings() you select all nodes, so the code works in this specific case but not if you have, say a <span> tag at the same level. You can use siblings('.btn') or siblings('button') to select all siblings elements having class "btn" or being a button, respectively.

Answer (score 3):

Note that you dont have to replace the class `btn-default` with `btn-primary`, you can simply apply the `btn-primary` class and its styling will supercede that of `btn-default`, as such you dont have to perform additional operations.

```js
$('.btn-group .btn').on('click', function() { // On the click event for each button
  $(this) // get the button being clicked
    .addClass('btn-primary') // add the `btn-primary` class
    .siblings('.btn-primary') // get all sibling buttons which may already be selected
    .removeClass('btn-primary'); // remove the selected class
});
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group pull-right">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="today">Today</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="this_week">This Week</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="this_month">This Month</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="custom">Custom</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Even though the OP asks about removing btn-default, I find this solution is way better

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `.toggleClass()`

```js
var buttons = $("button");
buttons.on("click", function() {
  buttons.toggleClass("btn-default", true).removeClass("btn-primary")
  .filter(this).toggleClass("btn-primary btn-default");
})
```

```css
.btn-primary {
  background:yellow;
}

.btn-default {
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group pull-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="today">Today</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="this_week">This Week</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="this_month">This Month</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="custom">Custom</button>
      </div>
```