# jQuery toggle classes between buttons in Bootstrap Button Group; set one and unset the other where other is not set

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a two button Bootstrap button group (True/False) buttons and want to unset/unclick one when the other is clicked - when True is clicked, True is active with a class; and False becomes unclicked and set with another class.

Here is the HTML page I am testing with:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Button Test</title>
        <link href="public/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="public/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <style>
            .squareUpButton {
                border-radius:0px;
            }
            .resolveButtonOff {
                background-color: #FFFFFF;
                border: 1px solid #00953a;
                color: #00953a !important;
                font-size: 8pt;
                padding: 7px;
            }
            .resolveButtonOn {
                background-color: #00953a;
                border: 1px solid #00953a;
                color: #FFFFFF !important;
                font-size: 8pt;
                padding: 7px;
            }
            .trueFalseButtonOff {
                background-color: #FFFFFF;
                border: 1px solid #005980;
                color: #005980 !important;
                font-size: 8pt;
                padding: 7px;
            }
            .trueFalseButtonOn {
                background-color: #005980;
                border: 1px solid #005980;
                color: #FFFFFF !important;
                font-size: 8pt;
                padding: 7px;
            }
            .remedyButtonR:not (:last-child) {
                border-right: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <div class="btn-group" style="width:100%">
                        <button id="house_Rules_True_Button" type="button" class="btn squareUpButton trueFalseButtonOff" style="width:50%;">TRUE</button>
                        <button id="house_Rules_False_Button" type="button" class="btn squareUpButton trueFalseButtonOff" style="width:50%;">FALSE</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group" style="width:100%">
                        <button id="house_Rules_Resolved_Button" type="button" class="btn squareUpButton resolveButtonOff" style="width:99.5%;">RESOLVED</button>
                    </div>
                    <input name="house_Rules">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        $("button[id$='_Resolved_Button'").on('click', function () {
            // Get the field value...
            var fieldName = $(this).prop("id");
            console.log("button_Resolved_Button - fieldName = " + fieldName);
            var fieldIndex = fieldName.indexOf("_Resolved");
            console.log("button_Resolved_Button - fieldIndex = " + fieldIndex);
            fieldName = fieldName.substring(0, fieldIndex);
            console.log("button_Resolved_Button - fieldName = " + fieldName);
            var fieldID = "input[name='" + fieldName + "']";
            console.log("button_Resolved_Button - fieldID = " + fieldID);
            var currentValue = $(fieldID).val();
            console.log("button_Resolved_Button - currentValue = " + currentValue);

            if(currentValue == "resolved") {
                // Set to nothing...
                $(fieldID).val("");
            } else {
                // Set the field...
                $(fieldID).val("resolved");
            }

            $(this).toggleClass("resolveButtonOff resolveButtonOn");
        });

        $("button[id$='_True_Button'").on('click', function () {
            // Get the field value...
            var fieldName = $(this).prop("id");         
            var fieldIndex = fieldName.indexOf("_True");
            fieldName = fieldName.substring(0, fieldIndex);
            console.log("button_True_Button - fieldName = " + fieldName);
            var fieldID = "input[name='" + fieldName + "']";
            console.log("button_True_Button - fieldID = " + fieldID);
            var currentValue = $(fieldID).val();
            console.log("button_True_Button - currentValue = " + currentValue);

            // Need to check the value...
            if(currentValue == "" || currentValue == null) {
                // Just toggle...
                $(this).toggleClass("trueFalseButtonOff trueFalseButtonOn");
                // Set the field...
                $(fieldID).val("true");
            }
            if(currentValue == "true") {
                // Just toggle...
                $(this).toggleClass("trueFalseButtonOff trueFalseButtonOn");
                // Set to nothing...
                $(fieldID).val("");
            }
            if(currentValue == "false") {
                // Unclick/unset the False button...
                var buttonID = $(this).prop("id");
                var otherButtonID = buttonID.replace("True", "False");
                console.log("button_True_Button - otherButtonID = " + otherButtonID);
                $(otherButtonID).removeClass("trueFalseButtonOn");
                $(otherButtonID).addClass("trueFalseButtonOff");
                //$(buttonID).click();
                // Set the field...
                $(fieldID).val("true");
                // Toggle the class...
                $(this).toggleClass("trueFalseButtonOff trueFalseButtonOn");
            }
            if(currentValue == "resolved") {
                // Do nothing?
            }
        });

        $("button[id$='_False_Button'").on('click', function () {
            // Get the field value...
            var fieldName = $(this).prop("id");
            var fieldIndex = fieldName.indexOf("_False");
            fieldName = fieldName.substring(0, fieldIndex);
            console.log("button_True_Button - fieldName = " + fieldName);
            var fieldID = "input[name='" + fieldName + "']";
            console.log("button_False_Button - fieldID = " + fieldID);
            var currentValue = $(fieldID).val();
            console.log("button_False_Button - currentValue = " + currentValue);

            // Need to check the value...
            if(currentValue == "" || currentValue == null) {
                // Just toggle...
                $(this).toggleClass("trueFalseButtonOff trueFalseButtonOn");
                // Set the field...
                $(fieldID).val("false");
            }
            if(currentValue == "true") {
                // Unclick/unset the False button...
                var buttonID = $(this).prop("id");
                buttonID = buttonID.replace("True", "False");
                var otherButtonID = buttonID.replace("False", "True");
                console.log("button_True_Button - otherButtonID = " + otherButtonID);
                $(otherButtonID).removeClass("trueFalseButtonOn");
                $(otherButtonID).addClass("trueFalseButtonOff");
                // Set the field...
                $(fieldID).val("false");
                // Toggle the class...
                $(this).toggleClass("trueFalseButtonOff trueFalseButtonOn");
            }
            if(currentValue == "false") {
                // Just toggle...
                $(this).toggleClass("trueFalseButtonOff trueFalseButtonOn");
                // Set to nothing...
                $(fieldID).val("");
            }
            if(currentValue == "resolved") {
                // Do nothing?
            }
        });     
    </script>
</html>
```

I created a JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/dzeller44/k27r39xL/

I found a few posts, but they did not help me solve the problem:

[Javascript / JQuery Toggle Active Class between 2 buttons on a button group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43169424/javascript-jquery-toggle-active-class-between-2-buttons-on-a-button-group)

[Toggling class in group of buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29793844/toggling-class-in-group-of-buttons)

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing unnecessary code.. Just add

```
$(".trueFalseButtonOn").removeClass("trueFalseButtonOn");
$(this).addClass("trueFalseButtonOn");
```

lines to your both true and false button click event.

In below snippet, I have added new code and commented your code.

```js
$("button[id$='_Resolved_Button'").on('click', function () {
   // Get the field value...
   var fieldName = $(this).prop("id");
   console.log("button_Resolved_Button - fieldName = " + fieldName);
   var fieldIndex = fieldName.indexOf("_Resolved");
   console.log("button_Resolved_Button - fieldIndex = " + fieldIndex);
   fieldName = fieldName.substring(0, fieldIndex);
   console.log("button_Resolved_Button - fieldName = " + fieldName);
   var fieldID = "input[name='" + fieldName + "']";
   console.log("button_Resolved_Button - fieldID = " + fieldID);
   var currentValue = $(fieldID).val();
   console.log("button_Resolved_Button - currentValue = " + currentValue);

   if(currentValue == "resolved") {
    // Set to nothing...
    $(fieldID).val("");
   } else {
    // Set the field...
    $(fieldID).val("resolved");
   }
   
   $(this).toggleClass("resolveButtonOff resolveButtonOn");
  });
 
  $("button[id$='_True_Button'").on('click', function () {
   // Get the field value...
   var fieldName = $(this).prop("id");   
   var fieldIndex = fieldName.indexOf("_True");
   fieldName = fieldName.substring(0, fieldIndex);
   console.log("button_True_Button - fieldName = " + fieldName);
   var fieldID = "input[name='" + fieldName + "']";
   console.log("button_True_Button - fieldID = " + fieldID);
   var currentValue = $(fieldID).val();
   console.log("button_True_Button - currentValue = " + currentValue);
   
      $(".trueFalseButtonOn").removeClass("trueFalseButtonOn");
      $(this).addClass("trueFalseButtonOn");
    $(fieldID).val("true");
   // Need to check the value...
   /*if(currentValue == "" || currentValue == null) {
    // Just toggle...
    $(this).toggleClass("trueFalseButtonOff trueFalseButtonOn");
    // Set the field...
    $(fieldID).val("true");
   }
      
   if(currentValue == "true") {
    // Just toggle...
    $(this).toggleClass("trueFalseButtonOff trueFalseButtonOn");
    // Set to nothing...
    $(fieldID).val("");
   }
   if(currentValue == "false") {
    // Unclick/unset the False button...
    var buttonID = $(this).prop("id");
    var otherButtonID = buttonID.replace("True", "False");
    console.log("button_True_Button - otherButtonID = " + otherButtonID);
    $(otherButtonID).removeClass("trueFalseButtonOn");
    $(otherButtonID).addClass("trueFalseButtonOff");
    //$(buttonID).click();
    // Set the field...
    $(fieldID).val("true");
    // Toggle the class...
    $(this).toggleClass("trueFalseButtonOff trueFalseButtonOn");
   }
   if(currentValue == "resolved") {
    // Do nothing?
   }*/
  });
 
  $("button[id$='_False_Button'").on('click', function () {
   // Get the field value...
   var fieldName = $(this).prop("id");
   var fieldIndex = fieldName.indexOf("_False");
   fieldName = fieldName.substring(0, fieldIndex);
   console.log("button_True_Button - fieldName = " + fieldName);
   var fieldID = "input[name='" + fieldName + "']";
   console.log("button_False_Button - fieldID = " + fieldID);
   var currentValue = $(fieldID).val();
   console.log("button_False_Button - currentValue = " + currentValue);
   
      $(".trueFalseButtonOn").removeClass("trueFalseButtonOn");
      $(this).addClass("trueFalseButtonOn");
    $(fieldID).val("false");
   // Need to check the value...
   /*if(currentValue == "" || currentValue == null) {
    // Just toggle...
    $(this).toggleClass("trueFalseButtonOff trueFalseButtonOn");
    // Set the field...
    $(fieldID).val("false");
   }
   if(currentValue == "true") {
    // Unclick/unset the False button...
    var buttonID = $(this).prop("id");
    buttonID = buttonID.replace("True", "False");
    var otherButtonID = buttonID.replace("False", "True");
    console.log("button_True_Button - otherButtonID = " + otherButtonID);
    $(otherButtonID).removeClass("trueFalseButtonOn");
    $(otherButtonID).addClass("trueFalseButtonOff");
    // Set the field...
    $(fieldID).val("false");
    // Toggle the class...
    $(this).toggleClass("trueFalseButtonOff trueFalseButtonOn");
   }
   if(currentValue == "false") {
    // Just toggle...
    $(this).toggleClass("trueFalseButtonOff trueFalseButtonOn");
    // Set to nothing...
    $(fieldID).val("");
   }
   if(currentValue == "resolved") {
    // Do nothing?
   }*/
  });
```

```css
.squareUpButton {
    border-radius:0px;
   }
   .resolveButtonOff {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #00953a;
    color: #00953a !important;
    font-size: 8pt;
    padding: 7px;
   }
   .resolveButtonOn {
    background-color: #00953a;
    border: 1px solid #00953a;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    font-size: 8pt;
    padding: 7px;
   }
   .trueFalseButtonOff {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #005980;
    color: #005980 !important;
    font-size: 8pt;
    padding: 7px;
   }
   .trueFalseButtonOn {
    background-color: #005980;
    border: 1px solid #005980;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    font-size: 8pt;
    padding: 7px;
   }
   .remedyButtonR:not (:last-child) {
    border-right: none;
   }
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Button Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
     <div class="btn-group" style="width:100%">
      <button id="house_Rules_True_Button" type="button" class="btn squareUpButton trueFalseButtonOff" style="width:50%;">TRUE</button>
      <button id="house_Rules_False_Button" type="button" class="btn squareUpButton trueFalseButtonOff" style="width:50%;">FALSE</button>
     </div>
     <div class="btn-group" style="width:100%">
      <button id="house_Rules_Resolved_Button" type="button" class="btn squareUpButton resolveButtonOff" style="width:99.5%;">RESOLVED</button>
     </div>
     <input name="house_Rules">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

You can also test it on fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/k27r39xL/7/

Happy coding :)

Comment: This leaves the trueFalseButtonOff class off the button.  Maybe then change the default button style so it will be applied.

Comment: Makes sense.. We dont need trueFalseButtonOff class. it should be .squareUpButton {} or .button{}

Comment: This works great with one set of buttons.  How would I use for more than one set?  Meaning the class is the selector and it resets all buttons, not just the one I am toggling between.  If you select True on one button set and then click False on the other button set, it removes the True button on the first set.  I updated my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dzeller44/k27r39xL/18/

Comment: Good question.. just change $(".trueFalseButtonOn").removeClass("trueFalseButtonOn"); to $(this).parent().find(".trueFalseButtonOn").removeClass("trueFalseButtonOn");    https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/k27r39xL/21/

Answer (score 0):

You are toggling 2 classes that are not there initially so when you click one button it will apply the toggle on both.  I replaced your toggle method with this:

```
$("#toggleHolder button").removeClass("trueFalseButtonOn trueFalseButtonOff");
  $(this).addClass("trueFalseButtonOn");
  currentValue = $(this).text();
  $(this).siblings("button").addClass("trueFalseButtonOff");
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/71yz2vwd/16/)

I also added an ID 'toggleHolder' to your outer div holding the buttons so we can call the buttons easier.  The code removes the classes 'trueFalseButtonOn' and 'trueFalseButtonOff' from BOTH buttons.  Then adds the ON class to the clicked button and the OFF class to the clicked buttons [siblings](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

Comment: Also I set the true button to be clicked initially.  A toggle should start with a value assigned (IMO).